# How to pass request headers when using java netflix graphql client?

Tags: java, graphql, netflix, netflix-dgs

I am using `com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client:4.9.16` along with HttpClient (JDK 17)

I am creating graphql client using below.

```
GraphQLCLient graphQLClient = GraphQLClient.createCustom(
        host-url,
        requestExecutor::exec);
```

And my request executor is based on HttpClient.

The `requestExecutor.exec(String url, Map<String, ? extends List<String>> headers, String body)` method can accept the headers but I am not seeing a graphql client method that can pass or accept httpheader.

What I am currently using is -

```
var request = new GraphQLQueryRequest(
        OurStoreGraphQLQuery.newRequest().oneStoreId(oneStoreId).build(),
        RESPONSE_PROJECTION; 

GraphQLResponse response = graphQLClient.executeQuery(request.serialize());
```

Neither of the above i.e. `GraphQLQueryRequest` constructor or `executeQuery` method has a overloaded equivalent that accept HttpHeader and in-turn pass it to `requestExecutor::exec` method.

1. What is the point of [exec method](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/blob/8f6eba40859138ef173690da8640a3defe6de56f/graphql-dgs-client/src/main/kotlin/com/netflix/graphql/dgs/client/RequestExecutor.kt#L29) accepting `headers` if it can not be passed by the user code with out creating a new instance of `RequestExecutor`.
   -- from where is the headers parameter picked up, how can i add more headers to the above headers param??

---

Probably I can use the below style as mentioned in [java-client/#plug-in-your-own-http-client](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/#plug-in-your-own-http-client) docs -

```
CustomGraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient.createCustom(url,  (url, headers, body) -> {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.forEach(httpHeaders::addAll);
    ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders),String.class);
    return new HttpResponse(exchange.getStatusCodeValue(), exchange.getBody());
});

GraphQLResponse graphQLResponse = client.executeQuery(query, emptyMap(), "SubmitReview");
String submittedBy = graphQLResponse.extractValueAsObject("submitReview.submittedBy", String.class);
```

-- but looks like i will have to create a custom client instance each time my header changes. Is that right??
-- Using the above suggested approach, it does not look like i can use the same requestExecutor i.e requestExecutor::exec in a generic approach.